# Keep jquery dropdown menu open on the new page of web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a kind of drop down menu. But when I click some submenu link, the new page of my web site is opening, but the menu is closing. But on the new page of the web-site active menu must be open! I think that it is necessary to find active menu, and after that remove style="display:none" using the ajax code. But I have some difficulties with it.

I tried to implement what I have in simple way on JSFiddle: [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dmitry313/dfgjx22j/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clickme">Click me 1</a>

        <ul style="display:none">
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clickme">Click me 2</a>

            <ul style="display:none">
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

**AJAX:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#menu li > a').click(function (e) {

        if ($(this).next('ul').length > 0) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var subNav = $(this).next('ul');

            if (subNav.is(':visible')) {
                subNav.slideUp('normal')
                $(this).removeClass("selected");
            } else {
                $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                subNav.slideDown('normal');
                $("a.selected").removeClass("selected");
                $(this).addClass("selected");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not even sure this is possible if you are opening a new page. Interesting.

Comment: I'm confused.  The code you posted here is not Ajax, it's just JQuery.  Are you using Ajax or are you using a normal hyperlink to take the user to the selected page?  Also, can you also include your CSS?  I see you removing a `selected` class, but I don't see the CSS for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give your dropdown link href an extra hashtag parameter

   `<a class="dropdown-class-name" href="http://www.yourpage/#dropdown-link-name">Dropdown link</a>`

   Also give your dropdownlink a unique class name.
2. Give the dropdown ul also a unique class name

   `<ul class="sub-level-1" style="display:none">`
3. When the new page loads, check if the url contains the text #dropdown-link-name, and if it does,     set the style of the dropdown element to display:block

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       if (window.location.href.indexOf("#dropdown-link-name") > -1) {
           $('.dropdown-class-name').closest(".sub-level-1").css("display","block");
       }
   });
   ```

   In this way you have to make a new jquery ready function for every submenu block.
    I can't give you a jsfiddle, but I tested this locally and it works.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but this code opens all menus, but I need to keep open only active one

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. You saved a lot of time for me. I'm very appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Find the current path from URL and based on this you can remove `display:none` property.

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
path = decodeURIComponent(path);

$("#menu li a").each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
        $(this).closest('li').css('display:none');
    }
});
```

**NOTE** : Untested

Answer (score 0):

You should have some kind of a script to render you this menu, no? I would consider a solution in which your menu rendering script will assign class like "open" to all parents of a menu item you are in, and "active" to this item itself. Then you can hide/show it by pure css, without any js. This also applies, if you are not really allowing user to go by link.