# Maintain drop down menu positions between page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down menu list of links fixed on the left side of a web page I'm in the process of building. As of now, everything is working fine except I would like to have one more functionality; maintaining the position of my drop down menu after clicking links. The links will have the exact same drop down menu except that the title and content of the new page will change. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5hvrwkjd/) are the core pieces I currently have in terms of code. If you click one of the headers it will drop down with the links available. Note, only one drop down is allowed to be open. If I had .html files for the links and clicked one, the page will "refresh" and the drop down menu will be shown as closed again losing its position before the link was clicked. I don't know how to modify the code to do what I want so I was hoping someone can help me. I would like to stick with just HTML, JS, and CSS if that's possible. Thanks, Here's the JS straight from the link

```
// Gotta give credit where credit is due
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911424/have-only-one-drop-down-panel-open-on-click-using-html-js-and-css
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("drop-down");
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function () {
         var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
         var maxHeight = panel.style.maxHeight;

         //Collapse all divs first
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("drop-down-panel");
        for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            divs[i].style.maxHeight = null;
            divs[i].previousElementSibling.classList.remove("active"); 
        }

        this.classList.toggle("active")

        if (maxHeight) {
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            this.classList.remove("active");
        } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: so you want the same dropdowns to be open even after page reload ?

Comment: Yes, have the same drop down (only one can be open at a time) open after a link was clicked and a new page loads

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140252/keep-jquery-dropdown-menu-open-on-the-new-page-of-web-site